# How to count the occurrences of a column's value in a column of lists?

Tags: python, pandas, series

Consider the following dataframe:

```
    column_of_lists   scalar_col
0   [100, 200, 300]       100
1   [100, 200, 200]       200
2   [300, 500]            300
3   [100, 100]            200
```

The desired output would be a Series, representing how many times the scalar value of `scalar_col` appears inside the list column.

So, in our case:

```
1 # 100 appears once in its respective list
2 # 200 appears twice in its respective list
1 # ...
0
```

I have tried something along the lines of:

```
df['column_of_lists'].apply(lambda x: x.count(df['scalar_col'])
```

and I get it that it won't work because I am asking it to count a Series instead of a single value.

Any help would be welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
df['new'] = [x.count(y) for x,y in zip(df['column_of_lists'], df['scalar_col'])]
print (df)
   column_of_lists  scalar_col  new
0  [100, 200, 300]         100    1
1  [100, 200, 200]         200    2
2       [300, 500]         300    1
3       [100, 100]         200    0
```

If performance not important use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1`:

```
df["new"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["column_of_lists"].count(x["scalar_col"]), axis=1)
```

---

```
#40k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

In [145]: %timeit df["new1"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["column_of_lists"].count(x["scalar_col"]), axis=1)
572 ms ± 99.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [146]: %timeit df['new2'] = [x.count(y) for x,y in zip(df['column_of_lists'], df['scalar_col'])]
22.7 ms ± 840 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [147]: %%timeit
     ...: x = df.explode('column_of_lists')
     ...: df['counts'] = x.column_of_lists.eq(x.scalar_col).groupby(x.index).sum()
     ...: 
61.2 ms ± 306 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: I thought apply was faster than creating list comprehension.

Comment: @The6thSense - Added timings

Answer (score 1):

You use count and apply.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
in_df = pd.DataFrame({"column_of_lists": [[100, 200, 300] , 
                                        [100, 200, 200], 
                                        [300, 500], [100, 100]],
            "scalar_col": [100, 200, 300, 200]})
in_df["Match_Count"] = in_df.apply(lambda x:x["column_of_lists"].count(x["scalar_col"]), axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
column_of_lists  scalar_col  Match_Count
0  [100, 200, 300]         100            1
1  [100, 200, 200]         200            2
2       [300, 500]         300            1
3       [100, 100]         200            0
```

Answer (score 1):

A vectorized approach for larger lists would be using [`DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and then [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html)

```
x = df.explode('column_of_lists')
df['counts'] = x.column_of_lists.eq(x.scalar_col).groupby(x.index).sum()
```

Output

```
   column_of_lists  scalar_col  counts
0  [100, 200, 300]         100       1
1  [100, 200, 200]         200       2
2       [300, 500]         300       1
3       [100, 100]         200       0
```